# Google Cloud Computing Push Notifications with Swift in background

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-messaging

I have and app where I receive Push Notifications with Google Cloud Messaging system while my app is Active but, if I send a notification in background, this is not handled until the app become active another time.

This is the method I use:

```
  func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

GCMService.sharedInstance().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

}
```

I don't know if is necessary configure anything else in the method `applicationDidEnterBackground` or anywhere

This is PHP code:

```
private function enviarNotificacionApp($titulo) {
        try {
            $senderIds = array();
            $i = 0;

            $notificacion = array('app' => Config::get('constants.general.gcm_app'),
                                  'comando' => Config::get('constants.general.gcm_comando_notificacion'),
                                  'titulo' => $titulo);

            $usuarioDispositivos = UsuarioDispositivo::all();

            foreach($usuarioDispositivos as $usuarioDispositivo) {
                $i++;
                $senderIds[] = $usuarioDispositivo->sender_id;

                if($i === 1000) {

                    funcions::enviarNotificacionPush($senderIds, $notificacion);
                    $senderIds = array();
                    $i = 0;
                }
            }

            if (count($senderIds) > 0) {
                funcions::enviarNotificacionPush($senderIds, $notificacion);
            }
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            Log::error("Error AppNotificacionController.enviarNotificacionApp: {$e->getCode()} - {$e->getMessage()}");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What keys are you using to send the message?

Comment: Where? In my PHP code??

Comment: You are using [this keys](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/server-ref) to send the message, which ones are you using?

Comment: 'registration_id' and 'data'

Comment: I have read better your trouble and if you receive notifications when your app is active it shouldn't be a problem of the push message structure (this keys are perfect, I recommend you to use the "collapse_key" when you improve your sistem). I don't know how iOs works (better with Android) but have you searched if your appplication is still running on background or there are a listener working when your app is closed? Your trouble could be that your application is not running on background or you need to add something else on your code.

Answer (score 0):

The Answer for this problem is very simple:

In the parameters of the Remote Notification sended by the server, iOS needs the `content_available : true` parameter. Adding this parameter to the Remote Notification I receive notifications while app is in Background or inactive.